# What makes Google pick one APK over the other for a device?

Tags: android, api, google-play

Heading to the Google Play Store for different apps, we sometime see that for the size section it says "Varies by device" or something of the sort. This can only mean that there are different APK files which are chosen by Google based on your device.

My question is, what properties are these?

Having seen the `build.prop` file for some devices, I know that there are at least these properties (given for Nexus7 to illustrate):

```
fingerprint google/razor/flo:4.3/JWR66N/711294:user/dev-keys;
board flo;
display JWR66N;
bootloader PRIMELA03;
sdk 18;
brand Google;
model Nexus 7;
device flo;
product flo;
screenWidth 1200;
screenHeight 1920;
platforms armeabi-v7a, armeabi;
screenDensity 320;
```

However, I don't think that these are enough, because when using the `google-play-api` project, I still get the same APK file as before for any values I provide.

**UPDATE**

As I seem to have mislead my gracious friends here, I am amending the question: the question was not about publishing the APKs, rather, downloading them. To be clear, I am using the `google-play-api` project, which allows for simulating a phone when checking in a device, and I can send multiple phone characteristics along with the request (in the form of one `AndoirdCheckinRequest`).

The properties listed above are the one I am providing for the phones. I have one for Nexus7 (a tablet) and one for Samsung Galaxy S3 ( a phone), respectively running Android 4 and 4.3. However, Google provides me with the very same APK file for each instance of the device for `com.android.chrome`.

Comment: So... you are a software pirate, and you are wondering why Google does not provide full support for software piracy?

Comment: :)) not so much. I am just wondering. I was playing around with the library, and I successfully got to emulate a couple of phones. But even so, the provided APK from Google looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check `<supports-screens>` in manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Play store will read this to filter your application in the play store.

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

It's not the only thing which Play store checks for filter apps, check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

it looks at the target SDK etc variable  ones put in his manifest.
this is how you can create different apps for different os versions.